# Safari stopped auto-filling saved password data, any 'fix'?

Tags: macos, safari, security

Yet another marvellous new 'feature' - Safari 11.1 now will not auto-fill any login data unless you specifically click the first field, select the login drop menu, select the login....

Is there any way to go back to the old method & prevent this complete & utter waste of time, every time?

To clarify, after comments.
The mac is unlocked, I'm sitting at it working. Security is not at issue; if I leave my machine, either I will lock it or it will self-lock.
 Any web site I visit that requires a  log/pass [already saved in Keychain, which is also unlocked] then requires me to click in the first box. Safari then presents a credentials drop menu for that box. I then have to click on it to populate the fields.
This does not improve security, it merely wastes time.

This is in no way an improvement on simply auto-filling with the same information, which it used to do until recently.
I could understand it if there were potentially multiple entries to choose from; but that would be an edge case not a standard practise.

Whether or not there are 'hidden text fields' is not really an issue, as this data was previously manually entered into the visible fields then saved to Keychain. Keychain wouldn't populate fields with data it had not already saved for that page.
This is not for the  the 'personal info autofill'  - [image] - which already needs specific user interaction for good reason, only site-specific previously saved Keychain log/pass information.

Comment: One day, Tetsujin will let us know how they really feel about things and stop beating around the bush. (LOL)

Comment: For what it's worth, this time it's a security feature which in time will be implemented by all browsers, Apple might be first but won't be the last with this one!

Comment: @bmike - sorry [not really :P] but I'm not really seeing how this is any improvement in either security or workflow. For workflow, it's an utter PITA, for security... it's 3 more clicks of an already unlocked structure.

Comment: We should probably move the security discussion to [chat] but I get if auto fill doesn’t fill - that plugs a huge security gap for everyone that saves their one password to everything and auto fills even hidden text fields that unscrupulous web devs scrape even before you “submit”

Comment: Does your Q include finding or assigning a kbd shortcut for this?

Comment: It includes anything to save the extra 5 clicks. Frankly, it's 'security by committee' - utterly pointless extra work. The machine is already on, unlocked, signed in & I'm sitting at it. If I walk away, it will lock again.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer covering a slight alleviation for:

> Yet another marvellous new 'feature' - Safari 11.1 now will not auto-fill any login data unless you ***specifically click*** the first field, select the login drop menu, select the login…

My personal grievance with this situation is that there seems no way to use the keyboard for this and being forced to use the mouse/trackpad to hit a usually tiny caret to achieve the desired result. Using the keyboard for this task would be at least much faster and less error prone.

Unfortunately, it looks as if you still may use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get to the username field, but after that all keyboard actions seem to be inert and it's back to using a pointing device?

That seems to be amplified by a bug. If you <kbd>Tab</kbd> *past* the username field and into the password field, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> ***back*** into the username field, *then* the information is auto-filled in for the most recent credentials and you may even select other identities with the cursor keys.

This behaviour differs depending on the page in question and also has its level of practicality depending on the page design: how many fields there are to tab into, before reaching the desired one.

On a relatively cleanly designed page like [Apple's developer program login page](http://oper.apple.com/download/more/) the behaviour is as described above. On other pages the behaviour can sometimes be different and even be more like it was before. For example, Microsoft dedicated login pages preselect an open field and it's just a cursor down + <kbd>Return</kbd> to go forward.

This was tested on 10.12.6 and with Safari Version 11.1.1 (12605.2.1).

Comment: It still seems a bit hit & miss. Tbh I've usually got the mouse in one hand, or close enough - by the time I've thought through the plan of action, I could have reached over & clicked it. First site I tested it on would let me get to the drop menu by keyboard... but then demanded I click the damn button with the mouse anyway :/ +1 for going to the effort, though.

Comment: @Tetsujin The inconsistent behaviour of the app and with regard to different websites may indicate quite strongly that my hopes of this being just a bug that will be rectified somehow are not entirely off the mark. – Re: your test. Did you use the Return key for selecting/activating? (I did not at first, expecting that action to activate the Login-Button for the whole Login/Password dialogue.)

Comment: I'm certain the behaviour itself - no auto-fill - is not a bug. It was mentioned in the release notes as being a "new security feature"... which imnsho is the biggest hogwash this year :/ The behaviour of different sites to the Enter key is, I suspect, up to the coder for each site.